# how to integration camel-ftp in spring4 mvc use xml configure way

Tags: xml, spring-mvc, ftp

how to integration camel-ftp in spring4 mvc use xml configure way
how to integration camel-ftp in spring4 mvc use xml configure way
how to integration camel-ftp in spring4 mvc use xml configure way

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- START SNIPPET: e1 -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
         http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">
    <!-- END SNIPPET: e1 -->
    <camelContext id="CamelContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <package>com.upgrade.ftp</package>
    </camelContext>

    <camel:camelContext id="camelContext">
        <camel:template id="camelTemplate"/>
    </camel:camelContext>

</beans>
```